# Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to select individual contacts with 1 status.

The problem is that a single contact can have multiple simultaneous statuses based on 4 distinct columns.

Active status supersedes inactive. If a contact has active and inactive status at the same time, it should default to active.

So far my sub queries work well independently but they return more than 1 value when a single contact has 2 or more simultaneous statuses in different columns.

Any ideas on how to return a single contact with 1 status?

```
SELECT Contact,
   ((SELECT 'Active'
     FROM   MyTable
     WHERE  Column1 = 1
             OR Column2 = 1)
    UNION
    (SELECT 'Inactive'
     FROM   MyTable
     WHERE  Column3 = 1
             OR Column4 = 1)) AS MyStatus
FROM   MyTable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered using [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) instead?

```
SELECT
    Contact,
    MyStatus = CASE 
        WHEN Column1 = 1 OR Column2 = 1 THEN 'Active'
        WHEN Column3 = 1 OR Column4 = 1 THEN 'Inactive'
    END
FROM
    MyTable
```

Comment: +1 but if other conditions are possible, then the query should probably *not* return rows. At least, that would agree with the OP's intent as presented by their attempted solution.

Comment: ...something like `...WHERE 1 IN (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4);`

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure of your question, but are you looking for a single status row dependent on the four columns;

```
    SELECT      Contact, 
    CASE 
        WHEN    Column1 = 1  OR Column2 = 1 THEN 'Active'
        WHEN    Column3 = 1  OR Column4 = 1 THEN 'Inactive'
        ELSE    'Unknown'
    END status
    FROM   MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a case statement instead of sub-queries.

```
select Contact,
       case when Column1 = 1 or Column2 = 1 then 'Active'
            when Column3 = 1 or Column4 = 1 then 'Inactive'
       end as MyStatus     
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run it, but this at least parses and should point you in the right direction:

```
select contact, 
case when column1 = 1 or column2 = 1 then 'Active'
     when column3 = 1 or column4 = 1 then 'Inactive'
end
    as 'MyStatus'
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE - this should work as it'll evaluate the conditions in order..

```
SELECT Contact, MyStatus = 
CASE
  WHEN Column1 = 1 THEN 'Active'
  WHEN Column2 = 1 THEN 'Active'
  WHEN Column3 = 1 THEN 'Inactive'
  WHEN Column4 = 1 THEN 'Inactive'
  ELSE 'Unknown'
END
FROM   MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are nearly there. What you are essentially lacking is the [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) relational operator e.g.

```
SELECT Contact, 'Active' AS MyStatus
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE Column1 = 1
       OR Column2 = 1
UNION
SELECT Contact, 'Inactive'
  FROM   MyTable
  WHERE  Column3 = 1
         OR Column4 = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT Contact, 'Inactive'
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE Column1 = 1
       OR Column2 = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand your question, and I don't think subqueries are the way to go with this, but you could try this:

```
SELECT Contact,
       (SELECT TOP 1 ActiveStatus FROM SomeTable WHERE This = 1 AND That = 2 ORDER BY ActiveStatus ASC)
FROM SomeTable
...
```

Comment: That would work if a contact was only active. But if he is inactive then it would not show. The problem is that I need to check for both. And if both are present then show active.

Comment: Are those the only statuses you need to check for?